# Can the scope of SharePoint Custom Field Type change?

Tags: development, custom-field-types, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm created a Custom Field Type by taking reference from this URL: http://www.mtelligent.com/journal/2007/9/29/sharepoint-2007-custom-date-time-field-to-default-the-time-t.html.

just wandering whether the scope of Custom Field Type can be change? let say it is only apply to a single subsite instead of the whole web collection?

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating Custom Field Type only for solving DateTime field default value problem, I'd recommend you to consider another approach: use `=NOW()` as the default value formula. I've tested it and it works.

Concerning your particular question, AFAIK, there is no way to change scope for subsite, but you can, for example, make this field type "hidden" (createable only programmatically), using "UserCreatable" option. For the full list of options, refer to the following MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544201.aspx